# Inserting text into an inline-block element moves element vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to code a theme reminescent of sublime text, and so I was writing the tabs.

The `div` elements looked fine (positioned in a horizontal line as planned), but when I tried inserting text, the `div` element would shift downwards.

I've tried `position: absolute`, but that required hard-coding values, and resizing the window meant the text was in the wrong place.

Is there a way to solve this problem, and why is it occurring in the first place?

```css
.tab container {
  text-align: center;
}
.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 50px solid grey;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="tab_container">
      <div class="tab"><a href="#" title="Test">Test</a>
      </div>
      <div class="tab"></div>
      <div class="tab"></div>
      <div class="tab"></div>
      <div class="tab"></div>
      <div class="tab"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of the `vertical-align` property is `baseline`. This property affects inline and inline-block elements. What this means is that the bottom of the text will be aligned with the bottom of the closest block parent's first line. This doesn't happen when there is no text in the element because there is no text to align.

Setting the `vertical-align` property of the inline block elements to `top` will fix your alignment issue without any static positioning

```css
.tab container {
  text-align: center;
}
.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-bottom: 50px solid grey;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="tab_container">
      <div class="tab"><a href="#" title="Test">Test</a></div>
      <div class="tab"></div>
      <div class="tab"></div>
      <div class="tab"></div>
      <div class="tab"></div>
      <div class="tab"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Follow up question, i'm trying to set margins for the links, but nothing i'm trying is working. I'm not sure if it's because of the trapezoid code, or because of vertical align.

Comment: @Gab [This is how I would do it](http://jsbin.com/leyibimose/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: If you want to handle text overflow, you can [use this](http://jsbin.com/xecivuhuki/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Thanks so much. How come margin and padding don't work in this case?

Comment: @gab Again that has to do with vertical alignment of inline elements and line-boxes in combination with borders.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make child folowing position of parent, so you must add position relative on .tab, and position absolute on .tab a

```css
.tab container {
text-align: center;
}

.tab {
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 50px solid grey;
border-left: 25px solid transparent;
border-right: 25px solid transparent;
width: 100px;
position:relative;
}
.tab a{
  position:absolute;
  top:15px;
  z-index:10;
  left:30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="tab_container">
            <div class="tab"><a href="">TEST</a></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"><a href="">TEST</a></div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried it yet, but I think you missplace a header here.

try it,

```
  <header>
  </header>    

<body>

        <div class="tab_container">
            <div class="tab"><a href="#" title="Test">Test</a></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
        </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `float:left;` to all the tab elements. Like:

```
.tab{
    float:left; 
}
```